# How to find an easy-to-integrate payment gateway provider for my company's mobile app?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, mobile-application

We are a young fashion retail startup and we’re now building a mobile shopping app (multi-platform).

We’re looking for a way to integrate payment into our mobile app but we’re struggling with choosing and integrating a mobile payment solution. 
The issue seems rather complicated - after doing some research we still have some open questions:

1. What are the most important factors when choosing a payment service?
2. How did/would you look for and choose a payment integration solution?
3. What were some difficulties that you encountered/we should prepare for?

Comment: pricing, architecture suitable for your existing application(means your skill set and background also) then you can also google about the reviews about that API (about security, reliability, scalibility, complexity, pricing and dev support )

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to look at their history.  How long have been around.  Do they have a large community.  What types of products (payment collection services) do they offer?  How easy is it to integrate their solutions into your website?  How easy is it to setup a POS system for swiping credit cards?  How much help do you get ensuring that you're PCI compliant?  How secure is the system you're using?

These are all things you can generally find with some online due diligence.

These days, it's hard not to recommend using PayPal.  In the very least, I always recommend including it as a payment option for buyers because so many people like using it to pay for things.  Your conversion rates will be much higher with PayPal as an option than they would be without it.

So then, since you're using it anyway, I usually recommend also accepting credit cards through it as well.  You can use PayPal Payments Pro for that part, and offer people both on your site.  If they choose credit card they'll enter info like they'd expect to, directly on your site, and they'll have no idea PayPal is actually still processing that on the back-end.  It'll make things nice and neat for you, though.

All of that said, the more options you can provide, the better.  You might want to give people the option to pay with CC, PayPal, Google Checkout, Amazon, ACH, or anything else you can think of.  On one hand, this could be confusing to your buyers.  On the other, the more options you have, the less chance of somebody not buying because you don't accept the method they want to use.

Another reason to go with PayPal, though, is that they're free to get started.  They have a vast array of features and different ways to integrate their services, so as you grow you can tie different things into your system.

They also have the power of eBay, Inc. behind them, and they're constantly innovating and developing new tools.  They also have a HUGE community of 3rd party developers that build on their platform so new tools are popping up all the time.

I could go on and on, but if you'd like more details just let me know.